# Does there exist a finitely generated, torsion group $G$ with a residually finite ascending HNN extension?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, geometric-group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $G$ be a group with an injective endomorphism $\phi$, then the HNN-extension
$$G_\phi = \left<G,t \mid t^{-1} gt= \phi(g)  \right> $$ is called the ascending HNN-extension of $G$ determined by  $\phi$.

**Questions**:

Does there exist a finitely generated, torsion group $G$, with an injective but non-surjective endomorphism  $\phi$, such that $G_\phi$ is residually finite?

**Thoughts**: Clearly, $G$ needs to be residually finite.  In [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404901000032) Sapir & Wise showed that an ascending HNN extension of a finitely generated residually finite torsion group need not be residually finite. I was wondering, given the fact that $G_\phi$ is residually finite, can $G$ be a torsion group?

I tried to show that such a group does not exist.  [This paper](http://math.ivanovo.ac.ru/dalgebra/mldv/desc-HNN-Ukr.pdf) contains the criterion for the HNN extension to be residually finite, but I can't seem to get a contradiction.

Any reference/examples would be really appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try asking this question on MathOverflow.

Comment: For the failure of RF, an older (than Sapir-Wise) reference is " R. I. Grigorchuk. An example of a finitely presented amenable group that
does not belong to the class EG. Sb. Math. 189 (1998), no. 1-2, 75–95
(Russian original: Mat. Sb., 189(1):79–100, 1998).". This is a finitely presented, non-RF strictly ascending HNN extension of the first Grigorchuk group (which in addition is torsion).

Comment: Nevertheless, I'd rather conjecture that there are RF examples. I'm not sure this question was addressed before, so, as far as I know, nobody made the effort to cook up examples.

Comment: Crossposted to MO https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428347/